# Check if value in text filed was changed and post it. JS. Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

So i'm having page, where we have `text_field`. The problem that when i press `submit` button, then he post full page(i mean each record that is on page). To exclude this, i need to check if the value has been changed in `text_field` or it has been removed. Do you have any ideas how to check it?

P.S I'm having autocomplete on this field, so when he changes the number in text_field, then the hidden field `hidden_val0` is filled by number(but this is only when you change value, not remove it).

Its HTML:

```
<input autocomplete="off" hidden_val0="hidden_val0" id="add_109_01000340001001002_id" name="add_109_01000340001001002[id]" type="hidden" value="111286507">
```

This is js code that i'm using:

```
var NewArr = new Array();

$('.something_here').bind('click', function () {
    var id= $(this).attr('id');
    collectID = $("[hidden_val0='hidden_val0'], [hidden_val1='hidden_val1'], [hidden_val2='hidden_val2']")
        .map(function(_, it){
          return [it.value] // Collecting 3 values witch we should pass
        })
        .get();

    for (var i=0; i<collectID.length; i=i+3) {
        NewArr.push(collectID.slice(i,i+3)); // Here we split values by 3
    }

    $.post('/do/it',
        {
            send_array: JSON.stringify(NewArr), // Pass them
            id: id
        },
        function (response) {
           location.reload();
        }
    );

});
```

Its output:

```
["01000340001001001", "", ""]
["01000340001001002", "", "2"]
["01000340001001003", "", "3A"]
["01000340001001004", "", "3"]
["01000340001001005", "", "5"]
["01000340001001006", "", "6"]
["01000340001001007", "", "7"]
```

How HTML looks like:

```
<input autocomplete="off" autocomplete_key="add_109" hidden_val1="hidden_val1" id="add_109_01000340001001002" name="add_109_01000340001001002" onkeyup="GetNumbers(this)" size="3" style="height: 10px" type="text" value="2" class="ac_input">
```

Comment: Could you be more specific? What output you want to receive?

Comment: @LucasM Sure! I need to pass data witch was only modified/deleted, not like now(he is passing whole page(all data). Like let's think that we have this output from the page `["01000340001001002", "", "2"] ["01000340001001003", "", "3A"]`. So that is 2 values. I've modifed the 3A, and now it becomes 16, so at the end i need to receive only 1 record => `["01000340001001003", "autofillled_id", "16"]`. Because it has been modified.

Comment: Also it should work when you deleting value. So we have same output on the page and we modified the `3A` to nothing(deleted value), so at the end i should get only 1 record back => `["01000340001001003", "", ""]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this: (this code was not tested)

```
var dataArray = [];

$(function(){
    $(document).on('change', 'input', function(){
    var hid1 = $(this).data("hidden_val0");
    var hid2 = $(this).data("hidden_val1");
    var hid3 = $(this).data("hidden_val3");
    dataArray.push([hid1, hid2, hid3])
  });
});

   $('.something_here').bind('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.post('/do/it',
        {
            send_array: dataArray,
            id: id
        },
        function (response) {
           location.reload();
        }
    );
```

Comment: Thank you for your message! But unfortunately i can't use .on function because we use jQuery < 1.7 on project and we can't change it. `bind` should be OK,

Comment: Glad I could help. Next time when you ask a question, please add as many info as you can. jQuery < 1.7 is very important constraint.